# Is this profile view bugged? (Profile Level=0)

Tags: starcraft-2

I have been seeing some profiles with level 0 even though they are not. Is this a normal 'level hide feature' or some sort of a known bug?

[image]

Comment: Would apear to be. Have you tried to log out and in again, to see if it changes? You can remove your border displaying your 1v1 league, but not sure about the level.

Comment: I play in EU realm. I tried to search for the guy, found the group and the guy. When I tried to view profile, game warned me: "Player does not have a StarCraft II Profile on your realm." Well, isn't this awkward? I cannot recall how I viewed his profile yesterday and now I can not. Probably I was viewing some other's match history and I found him, not sure tho.

Comment: Oh well, I found him again. He's in my league division, and still after the login, his account looks like this.

Comment: Id say you should ask him and give us the answer :)

Comment: Now he has level 90 appearing on his profile. This is awkward. I'll go ahead and ask him as you suggested:)

Comment: He thinks it might be a bug as well.

Comment: You should answer your own question then, as it appears to be a bug :)

Comment: Sorry for bump, but @AtlasEU, you mentioned: "Would apear to be. Have you tried to log out and in again, to see if it changes? You can remove your border displaying your 1v1 league, but not sure about the level." Then how do I remove the border displaying my 1v1 league?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I couldn't find anything on Blizzard forums, It appears to be a bug. I talked to the owner of the profile and he said he did not do anything to hide his portrait frame or level. In fact, you are not supposed to have anything to do to hide your level on your portrait. Therefore It's a minor bug that seems not to affect many people.

Answer (score -3):

I think it /might/ be a free to play account? 
They just added a few new features to the starter edition due to the celebration of "Spawning".

Comment: Please be specific in your answer, and post facts, and not new questions.

Comment: It is a possibility, but we will need a more solid answer than speculation unfortunately.